# sha-1 creation in vb .net 3.5

Tags: vb.net, sha1, sha512

I'm having a great deal of difficulty finding a function or sub for vb (**not C**) that provides an easy way to convert a given string into a sha-1 (or sha512 ideally) hash.

If someone could provide a function in VB, it'd be extremely helpful.

Nearest attempt:

```
Function create_hash(ByVal password, ByVal salt)

        Dim input As [Char]() = "string to hash".ToCharArray()
        Dim secret As New SecureString()


        For idx As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
            secret.AppendChar(input(idx))
        Next SecurePassword.MakeReadOnly()

        Dim pBStr As IntPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secret)
        Dim output As String = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(pBStr)
        Marshal.FreeBSTR(pBStr)
        Dim sha As SHA512 = New SHA512Managed()
        Dim result As Byte() = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output))



        Return result
    End Function
```

But this causes visual stuido to blue underline SecurePassword and Marshal at evey use. These are marked as undeclared variables, but declaring them causes other problems which I can't find a way to solve.

Comment: Edited the answer with the best solution I've found so far.

Comment: `Next SecurePassword.MakeReadOnly()` -- what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm not certain myself. I've been trying code from various sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for the System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

```
Dim data(DATA_SIZE) As Byte
Dim result() As Byte
Dim shaM As New SHA512Managed()
result = shaM.ComputeHash(data)
```

Like this (ignoring the salting you are doing at the top):

```
Function create_hash(ByVal password, ByVal salt) As Byte()
    Dim sha As SHA512 = New SHA512Managed()
    Dim result As Byte() = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password & salt))
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried similar solutions, but visual studio tells me off because byte is a type and cannot be used as an expression. Actually, that is one solution I tried.

Comment: @YsoL8 it's becuase `Dim result As Byte()` isn't valid, it should be as mdm has it.

Comment: What values would be valid for DATA_SIZE?

Comment: `Dim data(DATA_SIZE) As Byte` is just to represent a predefined array with some data in - just replace that with the byte array you want to hash.

Comment: @mdm I'm not getting it. If I use ' Function create_hash(ByVal password, ByVal salt) Dim data(password) As Byte' I get a convert from byte() to string error

Comment: WHat are you trying to do in that code you just posted? All you need to do is convert your password to a byte array (done in the snippet I just added), pass it to ComputeHash, and then you have a byte array containing the hash as bytes. You can then do `Dim hex as String = BitConverter.ToString(data)` to turn it in to a hex string.

Comment: Fixed it now. Was attempting to return the result to a variable set as string.